# How to increse Idle Air OR Gas - 1986 ford ranger

Tags: ford, idle, ranger

I have a 1986 for ranger that sounds sluggish on idle not bad just not great. 
If I push a little on the gas the idle sounds perfect.

I am wondering how I can achieve the same affect automatically?

Comment: don't forget to upvote that answer!    :-)

Comment: If you find the answer(s) useful, please consider upvoting them and if is the fix for your situation, come back and select as the answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on if you are carb or EFI.

First, make sure everything is in proper working order - clean the carb/throttle body, no vac leaks, good fuel pressure, plugs, wires, cap, rotor, timing, advance.  Any of these can give you a bad idle that may seem to disappear at higher RPM.

EFI - your IACV controls the idle speed.  If it is not idling correctly, it is likely that either the IACV port is dirty, or malfunctioning.  There may be an idle screw, but this is not recommended.

Carb - there is typically an idle screw you can use to set the idle.  You might want to also consider the choke, fuel mixture and timing.  Make sure these are set/tuned to factory specifications.

Comment: it worked exactly how I wanted. There was a little screw, thanks again.

Comment: I have another question. It's idling fine but it seems inconsistent. It will be idling fine for 4 or 5 seconds then surge(a mini engine rev) and continue this cycle. Any ideas?

Comment: is it carb or efi?  Carb, I would say something is out of tune.  Thinking fuel mixture. EFI I would say the ECU is doing something.  vac leak seems unlikely as that should cause a constant high. There is a possibility of it being timing related.  Something like gear lash allowing the timing to jump, which can cause RPM to rise/fall.  could be related to your previous idle issue.